# Add dynamic input field in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is there a way to put a dynamic input inside ajax? I am using [hayageek](http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php) jquery file upload. I wanted to add an input as hidden inside the form upload for replacing a file. Any help would be much appreciated.

The div that handles upload:
`<div id="replacefile">Upload</div>`

I wanted to put: `<input type="text" name="replace">`

```
$("#replacefile").uploadFile({
    url            : newurl,
    fileName       : "myfile",
    returnType     : "json",
    dragDrop       : true,
    showFileCounter: false, // show numbered list of file
    allowDuplicates: false,
    multiple       : true, //allow multiple file upload
    showFileSize   : false, // show file size
    acceptFiles    : "doc,pdf",
    onSuccess      : function(files,data,xhr,pd) {
     // success 
    },
    onError        : function() {
     // error
    }
  });
```

Comment: Where you want to put it? do you want to remove "#replacefile" and put input instead.

Comment: I wanted to put it inside the form generated by `uploadfile()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#replacefile").uploadFile({
    url            : newurl,
    fileName       : "myfile",
    returnType     : "json",
    dragDrop       : true,
    showFileCounter: false, // show numbered list of file
    allowDuplicates: false,
    multiple       : true, //allow multiple file upload
    showFileSize   : false, // show file size
    acceptFiles    : "doc,pdf",
    onSuccess      : function(files,data,xhr,pd) {
     // success 

        var input=$('<input type="text" name="replace">');
        $('#replacefile').find('form').append(input);
    },
    onError        : function() {
     // error
    }
  });
```

Comment: I got db error. but I guess this is working so I'll accept this. Thanks!

Comment: How about if I put an input value to it? example var id = item_id.

Comment: yeah you can. Put input.val(id) in onSuccess function at last.

Comment: Do i need to serialize the form?

Comment: `var input=$('<input type="text" name="item_document_id" value=item_id>')` is this correct?